# Bash - how to get a last character of a positional Parameter?

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

I am trying to read a last character of a **string saved in a positional parameter $1**. So far, I know how to do this only for the named variable, such as

```
echo "${str: -1}"
```

Could someone advise me how to do it for $1. Thought this could work, but it didnt. Thank you.

```
echo "${\$1: -1}"
```

Comment: You can use `"${1: -1}"`

Comment: Thank you, just an additional questoin if u know and dont mind - how it shall look in single quotes, for example as awk command? This doesnt work --> awk -v PARAM_NAME="clientid" '{ if ($1 == "\""PARAM_NAME"\":" && "${2: -1}" == ",") { print $2;}}'

Comment: @Jozef: I suggest to start a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivially

```
echo "${1: -1}"
```

The numbered arguments use exactly the same syntax as any other variables.

The parameter expansion `${str: -1}` is a Bash extension; if you need POSIX `sh` compatibility, you need two steps.

```
_=${1%?}
echo "${1#"$_"}"
```

The first expansion returns the string with its last character removed; then, we remove this string from the prefix, yielding just the character we chopped off before.

Answer (score 1):

There is also this syntax

```
echo ${1:(-1)}
```